# How to force the user to set report filtering criteria before running a report in Dynamics 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have a Dynamics 365 SSRS fetchxml-based report and pre-filtering is set up for the fetch xml query, but currently the user will see the rendered report before selecting the filter criteria.  I would like users to see the Report Filtering Criteria first and define some filters before the report renders, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is mostly User Training issue.

There is small hack provided you have parameters in your SSRS Report.

If you have any parameters in your report, you can set it's default value as none.

When you do that report does not have any data/parameter default value to work with and report will not show any result.

Now user will have to input parameter/filter value and hit view report button.